# Can not move divs up and down with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am really not sure what's going on, I tried a few different ways to do this and I just can not get it going.

I have div boxes with the same class that I want to animate to move up and down depending on which button is clicked ( Up or Down button ).

Here is the code (**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjdXm/)**):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sliding</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .haos {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color:white;
        width:inherit;
        height:100px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        padding:25px;
    }
    #btnwrap {
        margin-top:10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #big_div {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:300px;
        height:400px;
        background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
        overflow: auto; 
    }

    .small_div {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color:white;
        width:inherit;
        height:100px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        padding:25px;
        position:relative;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#upbtn").click(function(){

                $(".small_div").css({'position':'relative','top':'-5px'})

        });

        //start of DOWN button function
        $("#dwnbtn").click(function(){
            $(".small_div").css({'position':'relative','top':'+5px'})
        });
        //end of down button function

}); 
/*
--I also tried stuff below

$( "#upbtn" ).live( "click", function(data) {
    console.log(data);

  $(".small_div").css({'position':'relative','top':'-5px'})
});

--another try with the pure js and putting onclick atribute in html

function clickit (){

var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('small_div');
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
    var item = cusid_ele[i];  
    item.style.marginTop="5px";
    console.log("event is fired");
}

}

--and the final which I thought will work with .on()
var top  = $('.small_div').offset().top;

$(document).on('click', '#upbtn', function(event) {
    //alert(top); for testing

    top += 50;
    $(".small_div").animate({
        "top": "5px"
    }, "slow"); 
});
*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="big_div">
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
    <div class="small_div"  >Some random text here</div>
</div>
<div id="btnwrap">
<button id="upbtn" >Up</button>
<button id="dwnbtn">Down</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I realize that it is hard to read the code when its not separated in different files, but this was just a test example that I wanted to implement on a real website, that is the reason why it is all in one type of doc.

Comment: Can you try putting `position: relative` on `#big_div`, see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Second point - your + and - 5 pixels won't aggregate; they will just fix it to that value.

Comment: When asking js questions is is helpful to provide a working demo (e.g. at jsfiddle) along with the code you post here. I added a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Tried to put position:relative on the #big_div it does not work :( what do you mean by the second comment ?

Comment: Thanks , in the future I will look into using the jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
 $(".small_div").css({'top': /*==>*/'+=5px'});
```

OR

```
 $(".small_div").css({'top': /*==>*/'-=5px'});
```

But you need to keep in mind that you need to initially set a initial `top` value for those elements, either using *css* or *js*, otherwise the `+=` or `-=` operators won't do anything.

Check the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjdXm/2/). (Along with the change to `-=` and `+=` I added `top: 0px` to the `.small_div` rule)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you a lot man, and the version of the person under nickname "Dola" works also :)

Comment: @Novarac23 yes the version of `Dola` is also valid. Feel free to give both answers an upvote if you like them, and don't forget to accept the answer you that solved your problem and if the both solved it then choose the one you like best.

Comment: Ok one more question how do I stop the .css() if the last <div> is for example at the half of the parent <div> ? Because I don't want a user to be able to move the entire content of child div's out of the parent div content :)

Comment: @Novarac23 You should not ask new questions as comment, but create a new question out of it. But before that I suggest to try something with: `offset` of the last `small_div` and `offset` of the `big_div` in combination with the `innerHeight` of the `big_div` and the `outerHeight` of the last `small_div`. And if you don't get it work show your current state in a new question.

Comment: Thank you , I found a solution. What I did is just placed an  `if` conditional stament and asked if the current top position is something then don't do this, else do it! Anyways really thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjdXm/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#upbtn").click(function () {
        var top = parseInt($(".small_div").css("top"));
        if(isNaN(top)) top=0;
        top+=5;

        $(".small_div").css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': top+'px'
        })
    });

    //start of DOWN button function
    $("#dwnbtn").click(function () {

         var top = parseInt($(".small_div").css("top"));

        if(isNaN(top)) top=0;

        top-=5;

        $(".small_div").css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': top+'px'
        })
    });
    //end of down button function

});
```